# android:attr/popupPromptView is private

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-resources

I am working on a project 'Personal Health Monitoring System App'. I have done my project but when I build it I got the resource linking failed error. I have not to use the following resources in my app but still, I am getting this error. I am using 2 libraries. 
**1) LibWizardPager
2) SlidingMenu**
 I am using Android Build version 3.4. Anyone can tell me the solution to this. Thanks in advance :)

**my Build.gradle files**

```
         buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        //classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'android-apt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cse3310.phms"

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.0.5@aar'
    // apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    // library for make custom adapter easier.
    implementation 'com.github.amigold.fundapter2:library:1.01'
    // library for communicating btw components easier.
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.5.0'
    implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.1.5'
    implementation 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:library:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.itsmechlark:android-times-square:1.1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.2'
    implementation project(':PHMS:libs:LibWizardPager')
    implementation project(':PHMS:libs:SlidingMenu')
}
```

````
C:\Users\Qasim-PC\Desktop\Personal-Health-Monitoring-System\PHMS\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1955: error: resource android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private.
C:\Users\Qasim-PC\Desktop\Personal-Health-Monitoring-System\PHMS\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2309: error: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private.
error: failed linking references.```
````

Comment: Plz, add your build.gradle (Project level) &  my build.gradle (App level)

Comment: @Sandun I have attached, please check

Comment: try deleting build files and rebuild project.?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi   i did it but still same error

Comment: Gradle-> Task -> Build -> CompileDebugSources try this.

Comment: Hey @QasimAbbasi you found the solution?